# Ajax doesn't hit C# on server

Tags: c#, ajax, function

I have to use `JQuery.Ajax()` to autocomplete some fields. The problem is that it works on local but not once on the server. I wrote a test page where I only call Ajax (Test.aspx).

**JQuery in Test.aspx:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Test.aspx/getData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '{}', // same problem without that line

            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The url is good : when I only specify `url : "Test.aspx"` it fires Page_Load.
When I specify `url : "Test.aspx/getData"` it doesn't hit the function and Ajax returns the whole HTML page (meaning that it could not reach the function). I also tested `url : "Test.aspx/getData/"`without success.

**C# in Test.aspx.cs**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string getData()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> name = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    name.Add("1", "Valeur 1");
    name.Add("2", "Valeur 2");
    string myJsonString = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(name);
    return myJsonString;
}
```

Here I think I have specified all the required stuff: `WebMethod`, the static attribute, the function returns a JSON oject...

In my web.config, I have this line in system.web :

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e3"/>
</httpModules>
```

My application is hosted on a Windows Server 2008 (IIS 6.1).

I spent hours on that problem and didn't find anything on the web to resolve it.

**Edit 1 :**

I also tried `PageMethods.getData` after including `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />`inside the form. The result is still the HTML page.

Comment: Try removing `data` attribute from the `ajax` call, since your `WebMethod` does not expect any arguments.

Comment: @JDoshi Same problem, it sadly doesn't change anything.

Comment: As a matter of principle, don't use POST to retrieve data. GET is meant to do that.

Comment: @Tomalak You are right, I modified, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your code.  Posted here works:

aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#doAjax").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Test.asmx/getData",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: '{}', // same problem without that line

                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
            })


        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="button" value="doAjax" id="doAjax" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Web Service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Test : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string getData()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> name = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        name.Add("1", "Valeur 1");
        name.Add("2", "Valeur 2");
        string myJsonString = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(name);
        return myJsonString;        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Apo should work in any web server.  Can you please let me know how it goes?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made your changes, but Ajax still doesn't hit the function (provoking "Invalid JSON" and the return of the whole HTML page).

Comment: @Apo edited my post.  This worked for me.  I am hitting a web service, as I had thought you were doing.  I had to change the line url: "Test.asmx/getData"  Can you please let me know more of your issue so I can assist?

Comment: I'm silly, I didn't notice that you wrote a WebService. To be honest, I didn't know that method.   
Anyway, that solved my problem, it works on the server, thanks a lot man!