# Jquery Ajax call to ASMX web service error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a ASP.NET Web Forms application that has an ASMX web service file with a single method at the moment. I am trying to call that method from another file in the same project, but it does not seem to be working. When I look at my console window in chrome it states there is an internal 500 error with the web service. using the ASMX interface I am able to manually invoke the method, but it doesn't invoke from my AJAX code. I have been unable to determine the source of my error.

ASMX Web Method

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string TestMethod()
    {
        string x = "{Name:Shooter McGavin}";
        return x;
    }
```

JQuery from ASP.NET Page. I know the click event is firing and I also confirmed that the code is progressing inside the IF statement if the form is valid.

```
       $("#AddSupplierBtn").click(function()
        {
            if ($("#AddSupplier").valid())
            {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/StockPileDelivery.asmx/TestMethod",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Usually if you view the Network tab, or even click on the error in console, it will give you the actual error.

Comment: All it returns is 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: Are you using Chrome? If you open the developer console (F12) and go to *Network*, any requests made to external resources will be logged, including web methods. From there, if there's an error, it will appear as red text. Clicking on it will reveal both the Request and Response. The response should contain the actual exception instead of a general 500. Also, where is the ASMX file in reference to the page your JS is on?

Comment: I use Chrome. I don't see anything in network calling the web method, but  if I expand the error in the console tab it states: send @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
ajax @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ AddSupplier.aspx:228
dispatch @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
v.handle @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3

Comment: The ASMX and the .aspx file with the JQuery are in the same project.

Comment: Are you in the network tab *before* you click the button? It will only start listening for calls if the window is open before you attempt the AJAX call. Additionally, I meant relatively, where is your ASMX in relation to your ASPX. Your `url` has a preceding `/` which is why I'm asking.

Comment: "{Name:Shooter McGavin}" is not valid JSON. Probably not the cause of your error, but still something to fix.

Comment: It's in the same directory (root). I tried several different paths thinking the format was the issue. I even used the http path with local host.

Comment: If I remove the following lines from the ajax call I am able to get the alert() to fire. data: "{}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",

Comment: @ChrisLombardi Can you please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759279/ajax-doesnt-hit-c-sharp-on-server/44770306#44770306